# What close reason best fits "requirements only questions"?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

What is the best close reason for questions that are just lists of requirements and nothing else. No attempt at code, not even a list of things I tried and failed at just a list of requirements, maybe some data that needs to be manipulated and nothing else?

I see how these can be `too broad` but they will get re-opened pretty quickly by the *this is very specific question, how can it be too-broad* crowd.

I see how these can very loosely be considered `no-mcve` debugging questions as well, as there is no code.

I know a `send-me-teh-codez` reason will not fly because it will just be argued that `too-broad` works. But then you get back to the *its specific, there is no way it is too broad* crowd.

It asks *Any suggestions on how to do that?* as the last sentance which screams **off-topic: recommendations**.

And the [particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39584386/counting-occurrences-of-tupleslass-objects-in-base-class-variables) that triggered this is not really a highly arrogant `send-me-teh-codez` which will probably garner more sympathy for the hoards that think it is mean to close questions like this. *Link is only for clear exposition of an example, it is not at attempt to meta-effect!*

*It has been edited after this was posted to include some unrelated code and is still just a request for code even after the edit, no improvement whatsoever.*

#### What is the most effective guidance in these cases so that there would be as little dispute about the close reason as possible?

Comment: both close votes and down votes should count for the usefulness of the requirements(question) itself only, but not whether the OP shows attempt, isn't? http://stackoverflow.com/posts/217578/timeline is a good example that the question itself is useful that still gaining upvotes recently even without attempt shown

Comment: that is a strawman example; that question is 7 years old and would be closed within minutes by today's standards. upvotes has never been a sign of what is on-topic, *send me teh codez* by definition is not useful because they are almost always **extremely localized** and will only benefit the OP.

Comment: It's OK if there isn't a close reason for questions you dislike and want to see less of, you know. Downvotes are perfectly cromulent.

Answer (score 5):

Every question regarding code is technically a request for code. While the user may be okay with pseudo code or an explanation of how they should approach the problem, these answers are generally less useful than answers containing code.

That said, basically you're asking:

> What close reason best fits questions?

Which is too broad, unclear, and kind of opinion based.

Ignore the implied request for code, and judge these questions based on the rest of their content.

They may be too broad, or opinion based, or unclear, or off-topic for other reasons, but requesting code is not a valid reason to close a question.

As always, edit the question if you can improve it. Downvote the question if it lacks research effort or is not useful. Close vote the question if it is off-topic or missing something that is required for it to be answered.

Not every low quality question on the site needs to be closed, it is okay if some just sit in a corner not causing problems.

Comment: yeah philosophically, every question is asking for code, but you know that is not what I am talking about here, I want to know what I can tell others is the consensus for these types of questions, so the close reasons will less likely be disputed.

Comment: No, not philosophically, technically. The best guidance is to use the best close reason applicable to the question at hand. If the request for code is too broad, close it as too broad, if the request for code is opinion based, close it as opinion based, if the request for code is unclear, close it as unclear. You see the pattern here? The fact that the question is requesting code is irrelevant. We don't close questions because they are requesting code.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see...

- The question at its [earliest invocation](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39584386/1) does fit the profile of a "requirements-only" sort of question, which in my mind would be closeable as "too broad".
- The question has had a [major revision since](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/39584386/4) which does include *some* kind of attempt made on their part, but they don't quite specify the error that they're encountering, which in my mind would make it closeable as "why isn't this code working...needs exact error message".

Let's assume good faith on the part of the OP here in that they actually *want* to correct their question.  Close it as "why isn't this code working"...but it wouldn't hurt to let the OP ping you once they've answered the question of what the *specific* error they're encountering is, since at that point, it'd likely qualify to be reopened.

Comment: If you read the edit, the code is completely unrelated to the attempt to sum the data in the way they want, so it isn't even *why is this not working*. To avoid any drama, lets just say, *There is no pearl* at this point in time, even with the edit and without an actual attempt and stacktrace/output and expected output, it is still closable. Just not sure which one is the most informative to the person. But this exact question is not the issue.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson:  Yes, I *did* agree that the question was closeable; that much wasn't in dispute.  However, I don't want to rely on a hard and fast rule which indicates a blueprint for *all* questions of this nature.  I mean, there's little reason for us to preach about MVCE and adding error messages if we really think the question isn't worth salvaging; I'd say the best conventional advice I have would be to downvote the question and walk away, if you don't wish to engage with the question any further.