# Do we have a way to report questions without sufficient code provided?

Tags: discussion, support, flags

Sometimes, I stumble around questions on SO that, very obviously have no code included, and will inevitably be downvoted within the next few minutes (if on a popular tag). I usually look through the flagging menu to find the best solution. Here's the path that I take. Let's say a non-duplicate post either includes a) no code, or b) is just looking for somebody to solve their problem for them ("how can I do this" type things).

- `should be closed...` is the best option - that's what should happen.

  1. `duplicate of...` - in some circumstances, yes, but not in this one.
  2. `primarily opinion-based` - not really, in these circumstances. It's a valid programming question.
  3. `too broad` - I would say no, because it doesn't ask too many questions. It is still a one-question question.
  4. `unclear what you're asking` - Maybe...? But I would still say this one isn't as relevant. Although you sould argue that a post without code could be unclear.
  5. `off-topic because...` - I'll go here next.

     1. (The choices for the question belonging on another site) - Nope, not relevant here.
     2. `Questions seeking debugging help...` -This is the closest so far. However, I *still* don't believe this applies due to the fact that it references "debugging help". Our question is just looking for general "how do I do this", which is much different.
     3. Problem can no longer be reproduced/blatantly off-topic/migration - all unrelated here, unfortunately.

So basically, I'm left with no reasons to flag.

Here's what I say to all of the naysayers:

- I am aware I can just comment that they need to include code. I usually do this anyway - I'd just like a way to inform the moderators that *wee woo, wee woo* - this post may be low-quality and not follow the rules.
- I believe posts like this are in violation of MCVE, because MCVE, numerous times, references "the code in your question" - obviously, if you don't have that code, then you're not asking a good question.

Am I missing something *super* obvious here?

Comment: [**Only** debugging questions actually **require** code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338755/whats-better-a-question-with-no-attempt-or-with-an-unfixable-irrelevant-attemp/338846#338846).

Comment: [What close reason best fits requirements only questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334887)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Am I missing something super obvious here?

You're missing the fact that we don't *require* code in questions.

> I believe posts like this are in violation of MCVE, because MCVE, numerous times, references "the code in your question" - obviously, if you don't have that code, then you're not asking a good question.

"MCVE" is not a thing your post can be "in violation" of. It's not a rule; it's a descriptive term to be applied to a piece of code. Some fragment of code may be a minimal, complete, verifiable example of a problem, but that's merely a *description* of a code example in relation to the problem statement.

We have a rule that, if you're asking for debugging help with your code, you must provide an MCVE for that debugging case. But that certain questions need an MCVE does not mean that all questions do.

Examples of perfectly valid questions that don't need code include:

- [Vulkan: vkCmdBindDescriptorSets, pDynamicOffsets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54330992/734069) The question is asking about a function, yes. But it doesn't need to provide an example of `vkCmdBindDescriptorSets` usage, since it's asking about the behavior of a concept in a API specification. A code example would add nothing.
- [How to create debugging markers in OpenGL?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54278607/734069) Again, this is asking about API matters and runtime access to extension functionality. A code example wouldn't provide anything useful.
- [does signed integers now behave differently, with regards to left shift?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54255693/734069) This one is about the changes in a language specification.

I can keep going, but I hope my point is clear. There are lots of perfectly good questions on this site that don't need code examples.